# Tem como usar o CakePHP 3 para criar telas para manipular o CRON como o SideKiq?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3, cron, job

Tem alguma forma de criar telas para manipular o CRON PHP com o CakePHP3 como temos a opção do sidekiq para o Ruby on Rails?

Seria interessante poder listar os jobs ativos, e também a opção de criar novos jobs, também seria interessante ter um log de execução dos jobs e também uma opção de reiniciar o cron/parar caso necessário.

Alguém sabe se isto é possível, e se há algum exemplo disto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que você está procurando é uma solução de background jobs com client web.

O Sidekiq possui um client web embutido para manipular as tarefas que tiveram falhas e até mesmo fazer o cancelamento de uma tarefa antes dela ser executada.

Para PHP existe o [Bernard](http://bernard.readthedocs.io/) que pode ser configurado de diversas maneiras, até mesmo com GoogleAppEngine e para ele existe um client web chamado [Juno](http://juno.readthedocs.io/).

Se você usa Laravel tem uma solução embutida também de background jobs ([Queues](https://scotch.io/tutorials/why-laravel-queues-are-awesome)). Para essa solução em laravel existe o [Horizon](https://horizon.laravel.com/) que só funciona com redis.

Para o CakePHP 3 conforme você mencionou a melhor solução que eu já vi é [Queuesadilla](https://github.com/josegonzalez/cakephp-queuesadilla) do [José Gonzalez](http://josediazgonzalez.com/2013/12/10/queue-in-scalable-applications/) que é mantenedor do core do CakePHP, porém sem client web para manipulação das tarefas. No caso do CakePHP 3 recomendo que use o Bernard que citei acima.

Já sobre tarefas agendadas (Cron) é uma coisa separada. 
Você poderia utilizar a cron do próprio linux, ou outras soluções em outras linguagens, mais em PHP tem algumas:

- [Crunz](https://github.com/lavary/crunz)
- [WorkerPHP](https://github.com/kohkimakimoto/workerphp)

Já utilizei o WorkerPHP e funciona perfeitamente.
Espero ter ajudado!